# Calculate Precision and recall in a-priori algorithm

Tags: precision-recall, association-rules

I want to know if there is any technique to calculate the precision and recall in a-priori algorithm. I did search for this but found most of the examples on classification algorithms with formulars as follows:

```
Precision = TP / (TP+FP)
Recall = TP / (TP+FN)
```

But how would I find the TP etc. in association rules?

Comment: Which programming language do you use? Measures as True Positives and False Positives can be calculated by counting these after the classification from the confusion matrix (for ex. in R). As you indicate from this one could calculate precision and recall.

Comment: I am using Java to implement apriori rule mining algorithm. @RuthgerRighart I am not classifying anything I am just generating the rules now I need to find the precision and recall of algorithm but most of the links on google provides the classification solution which I don't need so that's why I put my question here.